# Figure is alone on a page, even when there's enough space on the previous one

Tags: latex, markdown, r-markdown, knitr, tex

I'm writing my dissertation in Markdown and it includes a lot of figures in the "results" section. Since I really need all the figures and tables to stay in their order and subsection, I'm keeping them in place with `\floatplacement{figure}{H}` in the YAML for the figures and `kable_styling(latex_options = c("hold_position")` for the tables.

My question is, if there's a way to have the text float around the figures without the figures changing their order/section? As soon as I set the `floatplacement` to `h` instead of `H`, they are not staying in their section anymore.

I tried `, out.width="1\\textwidth", wrapfigure = list("C", 1)` in the code chunk options, which makes the text go on the top of the figure (which is good), but puts the figure ond the next page, even though there would be enough space for it on the current page:

[image: ar]

My YAML:

```
---
output: 
   bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: no
    fig_caption: yes
    includes:
            in_header: header.tex 
lang: de
geometry: "left=3cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm"
fontsize: 12pt
bibliography: library.bib
csl: science-modified1.csl
link-citations: yes
linkcolor: black
urlcolor: black
header-includes:
- \usepackage{placeins} #definiert den Befehl \FloatBarrier
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
- \usepackage{chngcntr}
- \counterwithout{figure}{section}
- \counterwithout{table}{section}
- \usepackage{microtype}
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{float}
- \floatplacement{figure}{H}
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
- \setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
---
```

My code chunk options of the figure:

````
```{r, include = F}
defOut <- knitr::knit_hooks$get("plot")  # save the default plot hook 
knitr::knit_hooks$set(plot = function(x, options) {  # set new plot hook ...
  x <- defOut(x, options)  # first apply the default hook
  if(!is.null(options$wrapfigure)) {  # then, if option wrapfigure is given ...
    # create the new opening string for the wrapfigure environment ...
    wf <- sprintf("\\begin{wrapfigure}{%s}{%g\\textwidth}", options$wrapfigure[[1]], options$wrapfigure[[2]])
   x  <- gsub("\\begin{figure}", wf, x, fixed = T)  # and replace the default one with it.
    x  <- gsub("{figure}", "{wrapfigure}", x, fixed = T)  # also replace the environment ending
  }
  return(x)
})
```

```{r figure-USB-J01-DDD-absolut-line, fig.cap = "Absoluter Verbrauch von J01-Antibiotika DDDs am USB (auf 30 Tage normiert)", out.width="1\\textwidth", wrapfigure = list("C", 1)}
```
````

Is there a way to let the text go on top of the figure (e.g. if there is space for it on the previous page, but not the figure) without the figures leaving their sections or behaving weirdly like they did in my example?

Comment: First of all there is no option `C` for the `wrapfigure` environment [ceck this](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig-doc.pdf). If you want the text to go around a figure, use `r`, `l`, `o` or `i`.

Comment: If you would use `wrapfigure=list("r",".5\\textwidth")` the figure will float on the right side of the page while the text continues on its left. But the plot in your example would be too small to be properly readable I think.

Comment: What happens if I set the `textwith` to 1? Is the text not able to 'float by' the figure?

Comment: You set the width to be equal to `\textwidth`. If the figure has the same width as the text area, how is text supposed to float by?

Comment: It probably can't. It's just something I tried because I don't know how else to do it.

Comment: And it still doesn't explain the exessive white space that appeared between the figure and the text?